# I need a vertical display of a row using php

Tags: php, mysql

At the command window I can get a **vertical** display just by adding \G to the end of the query.
SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = '1234567'\G;
I've tried replicating the same thing from php but it isn't working.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\G` is a feature in the mySQL CLI program, not mysql itself. You will have to write a loop to do this.